# How can I get a schema through the bolt protocol (perhaps with a cypher command)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the Neo4j browser, I can write `:SCHEMA` to get the list of indexes in a db. Using http, you can do something like `curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index/`, which I can *pythonize* with

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index/')
r.json()
```

Can I do something equivalent through the bolt protocol? `requests` can't handle it (`InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'bolt://...'`), and since `:SCHEMA` isn't valid cypher, neither `session.run(':SCHEMA')` nor `session.run('SCHEMA')` work.

I can't use `http` because I won't have access to the `http` port in my application (although requests via `http` seem to be broken anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `session.run('CALL db.constraints()')` and `session.run('CALL db.indexes()')` to get the two components of the schema. You (I believe, if there's a better way someone please correct me) will have to parse the strings inside the result cells if you want to track them programatically.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently my reputation isn't enough to +1 this, so I'll ignore stackoverflow's request for me to avoid saying 'thanks' here...

Comment: This was helpful!